# What is wrong with the code where ´setTimeout´ javascript function is not working?

Tags: javascript, html

For my site, I want to display some content using `mouseover` and want to display the content for a few more seconds even when the `mouseout` action is taken because the content contains some useful links. For this I used `setTimeout` javascript function to delay the `mouseout` function for 10s. But unfortunately it is not working.

```
<body>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="some_text" id="test1" style="height: 450px; width: 300px;">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" id="test2" alt="some_text" style="height: 450px; width: 300px;">


    <script>
        document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
        document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

        function mouseOver() {
            document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "0";
            document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        function mouseOut() {
            document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "1";
            document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        setTimeout(mouseOut, 10000);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What if the user waits long enough before moving mouse out? What should happen then?

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeout should be inside the mouseOut

```js
        document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
        document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

        function mouseOver() {
            document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "0";
            document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }

        function mouseOut() {
                setTimeout(()=>{
                            document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "1";
                            document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "visible";
            }, 6000);

        }
```

```html
<body>
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="some_text" id="test1" style="height: 450px; width: 300px;">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" id="test2" alt="some_text" style="height: 450px; width: 300px;">

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `setTimeout` inside event handler, like this:

```
document.getElementById("test1").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
function mouseOut() {
    setTimeout(mouseOut2, 10000);
}
function mouseOut2() {
    document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "1";
    document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you bound `mouseOut` as the event handler for the corresponding event, it will still be executed. The `setTimeout` you added will just call `mouseOut` one more time, and unrelated to the mouse event.

If you want to delay what happens when the mouse out event is handled, then do:

```
        function mouseOut() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById("test2").style.opacity = "1";
                document.getElementById("test2").style.visibility = "visible";
            }, 10000);
        }
```

Note however, that this may not be that user friendly. Users may *expect* the behaviour to be related to their mouse movements, but now the connection is lost -- certainly with a timeout of 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks.10s was just an example. My aim is to delay the `mouseout` function to execute not more than 1s later so that the useful links can be visible to the users.